# React Native Camera: Access snapped image

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I am using the react-native-camera plugin in my app. I am trying to take an image and then immediately upload it to an AWS S3 bucket via AWS Amplify.

My Code looks like this:

```
export default class Camera extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <RNCamera
                ref={ref => {
                    this.camera = ref;
                }}
                style={styles.preview}
                flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.auto}
                permissionDialogTitle={'Permission to use camera'}
                permissionDialogMessage={'We need your permission to use your phone\'s camera'}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}
                style={styles.capture}
            >
                <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}> SNAP </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

takePicture = async function () {
    if (this.camera) {
        const options = {base64: true};
        const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
        console.log(data.uri);
        uploadPictureToS3(data.uri, "image.jpg");
    }
};
}

function readFile(fileUri) {
    return RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(fileUri, 'base64').then(data => new Buffer(data, 'base64'));
}

function uploadPictureToS3(uri, key) {
    readFile(uri).then(buffer => {
        Storage.put(key, buffer, {
            contentType: "image/jpeg"
        })
    })
        .then(r => {
            console.log(r);
        })
        .catch(e => {
        console.error(e);
    });
}
```

When trying to access the file using the readFile method I get the following error: Error: file not exists.

What is happening here? Why am I not able to read the image from the cache folder directly after it was taken?

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks alright although there are some "weird" stuff.

You pass the option `base64` to the takePictureAsync. This makes the camera return the base64 of picture taken automatically, but you do not use it for anything. You can do `uploadPictureToS3(data.base64, "image.jpg");` And skip the readFile method.

Another thing is, don't know why it is like this, to get the image base64 from the uri we usually do:

`const filepath = data.uri.split('//')[1];
const imageUriBase64 = await RNFS.readFile(filepath, 'base64');`

So try the `const filepath = data.uri.split('//')[1];` trick instead of passing data.uri directly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Directly using the data.base64 seems to work initially, however, I am not able to open the uploaded images from S3. Preview on my Mac tells me the file is damaged or in an unsupported format.
Using the other option seems to work, although I get a new error, telling me that 'buffer' is not defined. Any ideas here?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You may have to add the preffix "data:image/jpeg;base64,${IMAGE_BASE64_STRING}", so try adding the "data:image/jpeg;base64," preffix to the produced base64 string and see if anything works

Comment: You saved my day bro!. Been searching for this answer for a day.

Answer (score 2):

i am using the RNCamera plugin in this app,this code show image tack by camera in app

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View, Image } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

export default class CameraPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          img : '',
      }
    }
    takePicture = async function(camera) {
        const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
        const data = await camera.takePictureAsync(options);

        this.setState({
          img: data.uri
        })        
      };    
  render() {
    const{img}= this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <RNCamera
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
          permissionDialogTitle={'Permission to use camera'}
          permissionDialogMessage={'We need your permission to use your camera phone'}
        >
          {({ camera}) => {

            return (
              <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.takePicture(camera)} style={styles.capture}>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>                
              </View>
            );
          }}
        </RNCamera>
        <View style={{flex:1,justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>          
            <Image  source={{uri:img}} style={{  width: 200, height: 200}}/>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }


}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  capture: {
    flex: 0,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderRadius: 5,
    padding: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: `**enter code here**`20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    margin: 20,
  },
});
```

Comment: instead of `img : '',` use `img : null,` and it will work without errors